# Create a new table by grouping the data in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, subquery

I have students and they eat morning and dinner. I want to have the name of every student's meal in the morning and evening.

The tables I have; Student, Food and StudentFood table.

```
Table Of:StudentFood 

StudentId FoodId FoodType FoodName
    3       1       1        a
    3       2       2        b
    4       3       1        c
    4       1       2        a
    5       4       1        d
    5       1       2        a
    6       1       1        a
    6       2       2        b
```

**Sample out, requested table;**

```
StudentId  MorningFood MorningFoodId EveningFood EveningFoodId
    3           a            1           b           2
    4           c            3           a           1
    5           d            4           a           1
    6           a            1           b           2
```

I was try;

```
SELECT
StudentId,
MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType=1 THEN FoodName END) AS MorningFood,
MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType=1 THEN FoodId END) AS MorningFoodId,
MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType=2 THEN FoodName END) AS EveningFood,
MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType=2 THEN FoodId END) AS EveningFoodId
FROM
StudentFood
GROUP BY StudentId,FoodType,FoodId
```

and result; :(

```
StudentId  MorningFood MorningFoodId EveningFood EveningFoodId
    3           a            1           null        null
    3           null         null        b           2
    4           c            3           null        null
    4           null         null        a           1
    5           d            4           null        null
    5           null         null        a           1
    6           a            1           null        null
    6           null         null        b           2
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close.  You just need to fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT StudentId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType = 1 THEN FoodName END) AS MorningFood,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType = 1 THEN FoodId END) AS MorningFoodId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType = 2 THEN FoodName END) AS EveningFood,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FoodType = 2 THEN FoodId END) AS EveningFoodId
FROM StudentFood
GROUP BY StudentId;
```

The `GROUP BY` specifies the unique key for each row in the result set.  You want one row per `StudentId`, so that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: When I try this;
Error:
Column 'FoodType' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Not working

Comment: Based on you current input- and output table, Gordons method should work - I've just tested it on SQL-server, and this seems to work just fine.

Comment: @FurkanÇALIŞKAN . . . That column and table comes from *your* example.  If it doesn't work, you need to use tables and columns that are in your data.

Answer (score 0):

An exemple of solution with CTE

```
;
WITH StudentFood (StudentId , FoodId , FoodType ,  FoodName)
AS
(
    SELECT StudentId , FoodId , FoodType ,  FoodName FROM @StudentFood
),
StudentMorningFood (StudentId, MorningFood, MorningFoodId)
AS(
    SELECT StudentId, FoodName, FoodId
    FROM StudentFood
    WHERE FoodType = 1
),
StudentEveningFood (StudentId, EveningFood , EveningFoodId)
AS
(
    SELECT StudentId, FoodName, FoodId
    FROM StudentFood
    WHERE FoodType = 2
)
SELECT StudentMorningFood.StudentId, 
        StudentMorningFood.MorningFood, StudentMorningFood.MorningFoodId,
        StudentEveningFood.EveningFood, StudentEveningFood.EveningFoodId
FROM StudentMorningFood
INNER JOIN StudentEveningFood ON StudentMorningFood.StudentId = StudentEveningFood.StudentId
ORDER BY 1
```

Full exemple :
https://rextester.com/UZXCB44107